# Digital Ocean Fully Managed Database pending COMMIT queries

Tags: digital-ocean

I have a fully managed database on Digital Ocean.
I noticed I more or less always have 3 pending queries that have long execution time.
Since the query was `COMMIT` i tried removing all transaction from my app.
They were still there though.
I couldn't find any resource on it, but I got the idea it might be pgBouncer keeping the connection open? Anyone know if that's the case

[image]